# evaluate the following limit else prove that limit does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The function/sequence of interest is as follows:
$(\frac{n!}{n!+2})^{n!}$

I have a feeling the limit does exist, as if we divide the numerator and denominator by $n!$ we get $(\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n!}})^{n!}$, which if we take limit $n \rightarrow \infty$, becomes 1.

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this,

any help or insight is deeply appreciated ?

Comment: Is it supposed to be to the power of $n!$ or is is supposed to be times $n!$

Comment: power, raise to power $n!$ . Sorry if my latex is abit confusing

Comment: No, you did it right, it's just an usual form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: $\left(1+\dfrac{2}{n!}\right)^{n!} \to e^2$, thus your expression $\to e^{-2}$

Comment: wow a factorial can also be considered a subsequence ? This i did not know, thanks for the new insight ! Thanks for the reply

Comment: note that $ n\to \infty \Rightarrow n! \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

What you have done so far is fine.

Notice as $n\to\infty$, $n!\to\infty$ so we can re-parameterize taking some $k=n!$, and take the limit with respect to just $k$ instead.

Then you have: $\lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\frac{k}{k+2}\right)^k.$

Can you complete the answer now?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{n!}{n!+2}\right)^{n!}&=\left(1-\frac{2}{n!+2}\right)^{n!+2}\left(1-\frac{2}{n!+2}\right)^{-2}\\[3pt]
\end{align*}
Notice that the first factor tends to $e^{-2}$ while the second tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$.